# Bings Maps - Read GeoJSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bing-maps, geojson

I am working with the Bing Maps v8 API, trying to load my own GeoJSON onto a Bing Maps as in this example: https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk#geoJsonReadObject+JS

I am creating my JSON successfully (I have tested it using the Bing Maps Drag and Drop feature and all of my points show on the map. https://bingmapsv8samples.azurewebsites.net/#GeoJson%20Drag%20and%20Drop.

I am trying to get my GeoJSON to automatically load on a map, and I am receiving a JSON failure, and I am not sure why.  (I am rather new to GeoJSON/JSON.)

Javascript:

```
function loadMapScenario() {
            var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
                credentials: 'KEY',
                center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(32.560116, -117.057889),
                zoom: 5
            });
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', function () {
                var featureCollection = Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.read(getGeoJson(), { polygonOptions: { fillColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.3)' } });
                for (var i = 0; i < featureCollection.length; i++) {
                    map.entities.push(featureCollection[i]);
                }
            });

           function getGeoJson() {
            $(function (callback) {      
                var data;
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: "/TD/PatGeoJSON",
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (response) {
                                alert("Hello: " + response.responseText.data)
                                data = response.RepsonseText;
                                callback(data)                                
                            },
                            failure: function (response) {
                                alert("Failure: " + response.responseText);
                            },
                            error: function (response) {
                                alert("Failure: " + response.responseText);
                            }                            
                        });
                    });
            }
        }
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult PatGeoJSON(string parent)
        {
            JObject jsondata = JObject.FromObject(new
            {
                type = "FeatureCollection",
                features = from p in pList
                          select new
                          {
                              type = "Feature",
                              geometry = new Geometry
                              {
                                  type = "Point",
                                  coordinates = new double?[] { p.GeoLocation.Longitude, p.GeoLocation.Latitude }
                              },
                              properties = new Properties
                              {                                  
                                  MemberName = p.MemberName,
                                  /// etc...
                              }
                          }
            });        

            return Json(jsondata, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

My result is currently a "Failure" alert with the JSON string.   Note: if I hardcode my GeoJSON as the result from the getGEOJSON function, all of my points show up on the map.  Am I not reading the JsonResult correctly in my script?

Comment: Change `data = response.RepsonseText;` to `data = response;`

Comment: thank you for commenting. Now I see Failure: [object Object], instead of Failure + the JSON String....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your getGeoJson function is asynchronous, so it doesn't return anything, this bing maps is receiving a null value to parse which it simply ignores and this no error. Specify a callback function when loading your geojson and when it responds, then read its value. Here is an updated version of your JavaScript:

```
function loadMapScenario() {
    var map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {
        credentials: 'KEY',
        center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(32.560116, -117.057889),
        zoom: 5
    });

    Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson', function () {
        getGeoJson(function(data){
            var featureCollection = Microsoft.Maps.GeoJson.read(data, { polygonOptions: { fillColor: 'rgba(0, 255, 255, 0.3)' } });
            for (var i = 0; i < featureCollection.length; i++) {
                map.entities.push(featureCollection[i]);
            }
        });
    });

   function getGeoJson(callback) {
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/TD/PatGeoJSON",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                alert("Hello: " + response.responseText.data)
                data = response.RepsonseText;
                callback(data)                                
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                alert("Failure: " + response.responseText);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                alert("Failure: " + response.responseText);
            }                            
        });
    }
}
```